# problems With wordpress character sets

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, character-encoding

We are working on a website and my boss transferred the site form one host to a different one. With this transfer came the problem, the character set has changed on the server so all our word and symbols like " ë " and " Ê "  and even " ' " normal reading symbols have changed to this geÃ«et and this  RosÃ¨.

We have tried doing the comment out  " //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); //define('DB_COLLATE', ''); " but then the whole site breaks down ... Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Show the code. How did the migration occur? From what database version? To what database version? Show the table defination (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname`) for the tables containing the broken character sets?

Answer (score 0):

`geÃ«et RosÃ¨` is Mojibake for `geëet Rosè`

You probably have `latin1` somewhere in the processing.

Search for Mojibake in this Q&A:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

The data can probably be repaired, but we need a lot more info to avoid making things worse!

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
SELECT col, HEX(col), LENGTH(col), CHAR_LENGTH(col) FROM ...  -- for a simple example
```

Also, check the WP configs.  How was the "transfer" performed; give details.